# Passwordless(MFA) login Linux

Tags: authentication, linux

On windows there is Windows Hallo with support for bio-metrics/pin/yubikey/smartphone app. Even if it's not a 1:1 alternative Im looking for something similar.

Is there any way to set up multi-factor authentication for Linux login (not ssh, local login) with support for using sudo etc to remove the need for entering a password?

Obviously fallback to password is acceptable. Usage of cloud services is OK as long as it's from a reputable and vendor.

Not for use at enterprise scale, just for a single workstation.
Maybe yubikey is the only valid alternative with PAM? Would prefer using the smartphone for authentication since it's something i already have with me everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you thing with `sudo` and how it relates to passwordless logins.

Comment: Google authenticator+PAM  configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most 2FA systems support radius, so pam-radius will allow you to add 2FA to almost all linux services.  Here's a list of examples: https://www.wikidsystems.com/support/how-to/keyword/pam-radius/.

Comment: Seems like radius is the way to go, thank you :)